# How to install replacement window with no exterior stop

Tags: windows, exterior, replacement

I recently ordered a bunch of custom replacement slider windows for my home. I've been doing renovations for awhile, but I'm brand new to windows. My current home has casement windows. What I learned as I'm looking to install my new pocket windows is that there is no exterior blind stop because I previously had casement windows. There's an interior stop the casements used, but it's only about 2" deep and my windows are 3.25" thick.  The sill on the exterior side is lower than the interior sill where I measured the windows, but I do have a will expander with the window that I think will cover that distance fine (see picture). I also have the fun of sawing out the divider jambs as I'm replacement 2 casement windows with a single slider, which I also think might mess up the existing trim cap or flashing.  I should have figured this out ahead of time, but alas, I didn't.  It seems like I have a few options now:

- I can install the windows in the rough opening with no exterior stop. I can fill the gaps with insulation and then try to figure something out with the flashing.
- I could try to are some exterior stop over the top of the existing trim cap and then cap around that again.

Any other ideas on how to best move forward? I'm worried about anything that would require me to tear into the siding, given I have a multi story home and it is winter in WI.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Inside looking out, no exterior stop because of casement installation]
[image: Looking down at the sill, different sill height interior vs. exterior]

Comment: You should take a photo of the opening without the window. It is not clear what is the problem.

Comment: I added another photo with the existing window that I haven't fully removed yet due to local temperatures. But, you can see that there is no exterior blind stop holding this window in, so there's nothing to set the pocket window against.

Comment: Once you have removed the existing window, the bottom should either be flat (with a slight tilt) or with the leftover slot that used to encase the old window. If the latter is the case, you can simply fill the slot to make the bottom flat.

Comment: The bigger problem is lack of the stop to set the new window against from the interior. I can add more supports at the bottom but not sure how I solve the trim cap problem, or do I just install it on top of what's already there and effectively double cap it?

Answer (score 0):

The picture below shows details of a typical encasement window. Once the window is removed, I don't see any problem installing a replacement window with wider frame members, though you may need to build up a sill/ledge on the inside of the window opening.

[image]